# Why IHttpContextAccessor resolves without registration on Debug mode from VS?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a simple .NET Core Web API application (it is a default WebAPI template).

Startup registration class is default:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

The controller is very simple also:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ValuesController : Controller
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public ValuesController(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        return _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.TraceIdentifier;
    }
}
```

As you can see I have **not registered** `IHttpContextAccessor` interface on Startup.

And `ValuesController` works fine on Debug mode via Visual Studio 2017.

[image]

When I publish my application on IIS then I have exception.

The exception from Log file is here:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor' while attempting to activate 'HttpAccessorTest.Controllers.ValuesController'
```

It is absolutely correct exception because I have not registered `IHttpContextAccessor` as described [here](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/793#issuecomment-224828588).

When I register `IHttpContextAccessor` then all works fine of course.

So my question: Why `IHttpContextAccessor` resolves without registration on VS2017 Debug mode?

Comment: @mjwills `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContextAccessor`. Assembly is `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http, Version=2.0.1.0`

Comment: @mjwills It is not duplicate. My question: Why IHttpContextAccessor resolves without registration on VS2017 Debug mode?

Comment: I suspect your IIS and your local machine may be running different versions of .NET Core.

Comment: @mjwills My Target Framework is .NET Core 2.0

Comment: Did adding `services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();` solve your issue (locally and on IIS)?

Comment: @mjwills Of cource `services.TryAddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();` solves the exception trouble. But my question is: **Why IHttpContextAccessor can correctly resolves without registration on Debug mode**? I have not registered IHttpContextAccessor specially for tests on debug mode. And I can see the IHttpContextAccessor can resolves correctly without registration.

Comment: @mjwills My question is not about how to fix exception. My question why I do not see exception on Debug mode.

Comment: The duplicate link suggests that for some versions of .NET Core, registration is _automatic_.

Comment: @mjwills you think my VS2017 use previous version of .NET Core ? How I can check it? My target framework is `.NET Core 2.0`. Also I have nuget  package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All (2.0.5)`. So I think on my VS use .NET Core 2.0 on debug mode.